# android: how to restore an object, onResume, and save it onPause?

Tags: android, multithreading, object, onresume, onpause

I want to save a object(Myclass) on pause, and load it when the application resumes.

I tried everything but nothing works.

I'm trying to make a thread and make it run on my main activity when the problem comes.
When I press the back button(exit the application) and click again on the application, that creates a new thread and does not resume the old thread.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do can you give more details. Also look into onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: mkso is correct as far as saving and restoring state of the activity.  However, you should not be saving the `Thread` itself:  instead you would need to save the *state* of the `Thread` (e.g., if it was doing some work, you might save what "item" it was working on, or something like that), and then restore that state if you get a non-null icicle in `onCreate()`. If you want the thread to continue working in the background, you might be better off using a `Service` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make the class (MyClass) implement `Serializable`, you can then save it as a file when the activity is destroyed, and restore it from file when it's resumed

```
public boolean ObjectToFile(String fileName, Object obj){
    boolean success = false;        
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try{
        File dir = GetAppDir();
        if(dir != null){
            fos = new FileOutputStream(dir + "/" + fileName);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(obj);
            out.close();
            success = true;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){}
    return success;
}

public Object FileToObject(String fileName){
    Object obj = null;
    try{
        File dir = GetAppDir();
        if(dir != null){
            File f = new File(dir, fileName);
            if(f.exists() && f.isFile()){       
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                ObjectInputStream in = null;
                fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                obj = in.readObject();
                in.close();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){}
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: mmmm it wont work for me, because myclass its running thread.
and when i press the back button doesnt kill the activity.

Comment: PLEASE, do not use Serialization on Android, its incredible slow. Please use Parcelables instead.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you can't (and shouldn't) do what you're trying to do. If you have code that you want to continue to execute after the user ends a session*, your code should be running in association with a Service. The code should then be writing its work to persistent storage or your Service should allow for some binding interface for the newly created Activity to connect with the Thread.

*A session ends if a user backs our of your Activities. This is a different behavior than the user pressing the HOME key, which indicates that the user wants to resume what they were doing when they return to your application.